# unable to import .sql file in workbench

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to import `.sql` file in workbench but its showing error

```
Preparing...
Importing iqip.sql...
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give access to host.

```
   INSERT INTO mysql.user (Host, User, Password) VALUES ('%', 'root', password('YOURPASSWORD'));
   GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Showing Error
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'

Comment: Is it mysql or any other sql server